# Copying and pasting text only pastes a hyphen character

Tags: macos, copy-paste

When I copy a block of text more than about twenty lines long to the clipboard, pasting only pastes a hyphen character.

Why is the clipboard buffer so small and how can I increase it?

Comment: I wonder if it could be either a program error or a limit of the application you're copying from. I did a test and copy&pasted `101641` rows of text with no issues. Pics: [App I pasted from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2EH0.png) – [Clipboard history app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2NSR.png).

Comment: What app did you copied the text from and what OS are we talking about (macOS/iOS)?

Comment: I suspect it's an app issue rather than the OS. I have this problem copying text from a Chrome browser Jupyter notebook cell into Sublime Text 3 (http://jupyter.org/ & https://www.sublimetext.com). Tried using `Paste and Match Style` but no difference.

Comment: You can paste gigabytes of data and there are many clipboards the receiving app gets to choose from. [Here are some excellent apps and resources to look at what’s in the buffer and help understand which app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399876/5472) isn’t meeting your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

You should not hit the clipboard buffer limit in normal use, it is far bigger than a “block of text”. Depending on where you copy from, the source application might be transforming the buffer before storing it. Especially some websites have scripts for these kinds of interceptions in an attempt to prevent large-scale copying of copyrighted information – in these cases you can often work around using the `Edit > Copy` menu item instead of the `Cmd-C` shortcut, for example. Other applications might change the clipboard format after reaching a certain size, and might then have a bug when generating e.g. a Rich Text buffer versus a Plain Text buffer. Another thing you could try is pasting with the `Paste and Match Style` option, by choosing it from the Edit menu or pressing `Ctrl-Shift-Cmd-V`.

Comment: This happens to me occasionally.  if I click on the hyphen, the text appears.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem in Firefox, do the following:

1. In the URL bar, type "about:config". If it displays a warning/confirmation, click to accept or proceed or whatever. In my case, I had to click "Show All".
2. Click into the "Search Preference Name" field and type "clipboard".
3. In the resulting list, find "dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled" and check whether the value is set to "true" or "false".
4. If it says "false", either a) click the toggle button all the way to the right that looks like two arrows 69ing, or b) double-click on the line so that it changes to "true".
5. Close the tab.