# What happens when you paste an app into TextEdit?

Tags: macos, textedit

In the past, I have pasted apps into TextEdit, which would show something like the following. I always thought that this was a convenient way to store app icons (as .icns files), in case I ever wanted to back a list of my apps up (just the names/icons, not the apps themselves) to manually download and install later.

I recently tried pasting about 20 apps into a TextEdit document, and the document turned out to be about 3GB large. This definitely is much larger than the .icns files for 20 apps. What exactly is stored in this TextEdit document?

[image]

Comment: If you use `less` in Terminal to look at the file, what do you see?

Comment: @nohillside "Untitled.rtfd is a directory" :)

Answer (score 6):

When pasting an *application* into **TextEdit** as an **RTF** *document* and saved as **Rich Text Document with Attachments** it creates a **Rich Text** *document bundle*, e.g. **Untitled.rtfd** and will contain a copy of the *application* pasted into the *document*.

The more *apps* you paste into the *document* the larger it will be.

You can check the contents of the e.g. **Untitled.rtfd** *document bundle* by selecting it in **Finder** and *right-click* then select **Show Package Contents**.

There you will see a copy of each *application bundle* you've pasted into the **Rich Text Document** that was saved as **Rich Text Document with Attachments**.

Comment: My guess is the object being pasted is the icns object that contains all the various 2x / 3x and pre-rendered thumbnails of the full app icon - and not the entire code, but let’s see what the OP discovers.

Comment: @bmike, I know what I'm talking about!

Comment: That would be awesome if it embedded entire copies of the app! I agree - you do know what you’re talking about in general and in specific. If you paste Xcode - does it paste all aspects of the app or just the parts in /Applications? Similarly - could one copy a user folder or computer as backup mechanism - it will be interesting to probe how this was coded - if only apps are embedded and are runnable, etc...

Comment: @bmike, This is not rocket science, simple do it and then examine the _document bundle_, you'll see a complete copy of the pasted _application bundle_ inside the _root_ of the **.rtfd** _document bundle_.

Comment: I will indeed when I’m at a mac. I’ll move my answer to one asking how this works if that suits everyone more.

Answer (score 2):

Apple’s copy / paste mechanism contains multitudes.

When you copy something - many levels of data are stored into the pasteboard object - literally a reference to these apps is available to any application that receives a paste command.

You can start on understanding this rich and complicated behavior with two items:

1. An excellent app to show you what’s really on the pasteboard
2. An excellent write up on how this all works.

For #1 I recommend the pasteboard viewer - https://sindresorhus.com/pasteboard-viewer - it’s on the MacApp Store and also [source code is available under the MIT license.](https://github.com/sindresorhus/Pasteboard-Viewer)

For #2 I recommend the writings of Howard Oakley - his dives to the depths of the code and implementation yet writes clearly and in accessible terms. https://eclecticlight.co/2020/05/12/cut-copy-paste-inside-the-pasteboard-clipboard/

> When you paste an item from the clipboard, its data are passed to the requesting app, which then performs any conversion necessary, and inserts it in the document.

---

So to answer your question, it’s possible you have all of the various resolution of the icon images pasted into your document, but I would need to examine either your document or your exact pasteboard contents prior to pasting to answer your question. Hopefully the general answer above helps everyone as well as you dig into specifics.

RTFD documents are plain text with attachments, so you can examine them in the command line or control click to show package contents just like other folders in Finder.